# Is it possible to override a function in C++ child class without using virtual keyword to the function in parent class which is abstract?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, overriding

```
class Parent {
public:
    void func1(); // Complete meaningful definition in parent given.

    virtual HRESULT func2()=0;  // Bcoz of this function Parent class is abstract. 
};


class Child: public Parent {
public:
    void func1(); // Different definition in child.
};
```

Is this possible in C++ ? I am overriding `func1()` which is NOT virtual and it already has a definition in parent abstract class.

Comment: You can override, but using base class pointers/references to your `Child` would not give you polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Simple answer: No! Otherwise the the keyword virtual is meanigless.

Comment: @knivil: It is possible, and the `virtual` keyword has meaning - it is just doing something else [the behavior will change entirely!], it is *hiding* `func1()` in the superclass, and not triggering dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @birryree: Technically you cannot *override*, but rather *overload* with the same signature (different implicit `this` pointer) in the child class.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Technically it doesn't *overload*; it *hides* the base-class member's declaration.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I have to check how the terms are defined in the standard. I *believe* that it generates a different *overload* of the function, that *hides* the one in the base class. My understanding is that *hiding* is related to *lookup* while *overload* is related to different function signatures with the same name. But this is more of a *hunch* than actual *knowledge*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: C++11 3.3.10/3 is the place to look for hiding: "The declaration of a member in a derived class hides
the declaration of a member of a base class of the same name". For overloading, 13/1: "When two or more different declarations are specified for a single name **in the same scope**, that name is said
to be overloaded."

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That is not *the* definition of *overload*, it is just one of the cases. Consider operator overloading, the operators can be in completely different scopes and yet they are overloads. There is a different definition in 3.4/1 *Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions (13.1)*. Now the question is whether lookup can pick both functions under any circumstance, which I am not even sure it is possible and thus I might be wrong.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It certainly is the definition of _overloaded_, when applied to a name, which is what we're talking about here. The word is italicised, which means it's being defined (1.3/3). Operators are somewhat different, since the built-in ones don't have declarations in any scope.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The quote I provided (3.4/1) does not talk about operator overloading, but about lookup and overloads. That quote *defines* the term *set of overloaded functions* to be a superset of what 13/1 defines, as the *set of overloaded functions* includes all functions with a single name *in the same scope* **and** in **other** scopes if they are considered by lookup. If you consider the elements of the *set of overloaded functions* as *overloaded functions* there are 2 definitions. At any rate there is probably little to no point in continuing the discussion, I will try to use *hide* :)

Comment: My understanding is that overloading *is* limited by scope. A member function with matching name and function signature different than any of the base class overloads hides *all* the base class overloads from the derived class. If the derived class function signature matches a base class overload function signature, only the matching base class function is hidden. This confusing rule helps prevent hard to find bugs created when "best match" rules are applied. There must be an exception for operator overloads; the implicit base and derived *this* pointers will always be of different types.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[assuming here `Child` extends `Parent`, unlike what the code snap shows]

Yes it is possible [it is called hiding] - but you will not get a [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) behavior.

The static type will define which method will be invoked, and not the dynamic type.

For example:

```
Parent* p = new Child;
p->func1();
```

Will invoke `Parent::func1()`

while:

```
Child* c = new Child;
c->func1();
```

Will invoke `Child::func1()`

Comment: Thank u very much amit!! :)   I saw 2 contradicting answers saying 1) Its possible  and 2) Its not possible. Seeing 7 people (majority ppl) considering option (1) to be correct, I am considering this is the right answer. :)

Comment: It's not. The answer says "yes it's possible" then admits that it's not, that it's actually just hiding. However, the description of _what will happen_ is accurate. And accepting an answer just because it has the highest score is a bit silly.

Comment: More importantly, if some other methods from Parent's implementation call func1, they will always call Parent's version. And no "static type" crap will help you get around that.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not possible to actually *override* the definition in the parent (at least when talking about C++, "override" is normally reserved specifically to referring to virtual functions). Instead, defining a function with the same name in the child class simply *hides* the function in the parent that has the same name (i.e., in the context of a child object, looking for that name will only find the function in the child, not the one in the parent).

If you want to (and the functions have different signatures) you can also get the functions in both the parent and the child treated as overloaded, so a call will try to call whichever matches better:

```
struct parent {
    void func1(char) {}
};

struct child : public parent { 
    void func1(long) { }

    using parent::func1;
};
```

Now, you get:

```
child c;
c.func1('a'); // calls parent::func1
c.func1(123L); // calls child::func1
```

This is yet a third type of behavior though, different from having a virtual function *or* having a function in the child that hides the one in the parent.

With a virtual function, the selection of which function is called is based on the dynamic type, so if you have a pointer/reference to the base class, the function called depends on whether that refers to an object of the base or derived class.

When you hide the function, the function that's called is based on the static type, so if you call it via a pointer/reference to the base, it calls the base function, even if that actually refers to an object of the derived class. If, however, you use a pointer or reference to (or directly use an instance of) the derived class, it'll invoke the function in the derived class.

With the `using` statement, you get function overloading, so when you call the function (in the context of the derived class) the function that's called is based on which function's signature is the best match for the parameter(s) you pass.

Answer (score 3):

You can *overload* it, if they have distinct argument types.

You can *hide* it, in the sense shown here, so that `Child::func1` will be called instead of `Parent::func1` in code that knows it's looking at a child instance. However, as amit points out, you don't get dynamic dispatch.

---

```
struct StaticParent {
  void foo();
};
struct StaticChild : public StaticParent {
  void foo();
}

StaticChild sc;
sc.foo(); // calls StaticChild::foo

StaticParent &sp = sc;
sp.foo(); // calls StaticParent::foo
```

---

```
struct VirtualParent {
  virtual void foo();
};
struct VirtualChild : public VirtualParent {
  virtual void foo();
}

VirtualChild vc;
vc.foo(); // calls VirtualChild::foo

VirtualParent &vp = vc;
vp.foo(); // calls VirtualChild::foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is valid C++ syntax and will define a Child::func1 which hides Parent::func1 in Child.

However, this does not mean that it fully replaces Child::Parent::func1. This function can still be called explicitly on an element of child.

```
Child c;
c.Parent::func1();
```

Also, this function will *not* be virtual. Thus, the following..

```
Child c;
Parent& p = c;
p.func1();
```

will call Parent::func1 and not Child::func1.

Answer (score 0):

Most has been said.

Your expectations would be right if you talk about java. In java any non-private, non-final method could be overridden. Maybe you are more familiar with an other programming language than C++

By the way, two things are wrong in your code

- "**class**" must be written lower case
- the default access of members in class is "**private**". It is NOT allowed nor useful to override private members which are non-pure

Comment: *It is NOT allowed nor useful to override private members* is it not? There is a whole idiom (*Non Virtual Interface*) built on the fact that you **can** and you **should**.

Comment: Hmm, I have hear this term the first time. Googling for it increases my confusion.